# VBA Excel PageSetup Header not printed

Tags: vba, excel

I've got some code to update Excel page headers in my Workbook_BeforePrint method:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = ws.Range("A1").Value
End Sub

Public Sub PrintSheet()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").PrintOut
End Sub
```

When I print the without going to the Print Preview first the header is not updated.

When I go to print preview first the header is added.

How do I make sure the Page Header is correctly updated when I print with going to print preview first?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you check if the event code is actually executed when you print (by putting a break)? Did you try putting the code in the PrintSheet subroutine directly?

Comment: Yes, the BeforePrint code is executed and the page header is set. However it only takes effect when I do a print preview.

Comment: When I do ?ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader in the immediate window right after I set the header in code it returns an empty string.

Comment: If I do it in the method itself it does work.

Answer (score 0):

It worked as expected for me.

Make sure that Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") actually has something in it.  Check the sheet name also to make sure it's right.  Worksheets have a Name property that you can change via the UI and a CodeName property that you can change via code or the Properties dialog.  Double check that you're not confusing them.  Your code, Worksheets("Sheet1"), uses the Name property (the tab name).

Also, make sure you're not disabling events in some calling procedure.  You can put a statement in PrintSheet like

```
Debug.Print Application.EnableEvents
```

to make sure something up the stack isn't disabling events.

Comment: It is very strange. First it didn't work for me (had the same problem as Aetherix), when I tried it manually, once, it worked as expected (BeforePrint method got read), also with the VBA BeforePrint event. When then I changed the LeftHeader in the BeforePrint event method (Thisworkbook) and tried to give the Print command via VBA, it didn't want to read the BeforePrint event anymore. I can't explain that behaviour... When making the Header setup before giving the print command (VBA) in a regular module, it appears to always work with me.

Comment: @Dick Did you print or did you just go to the page preview? If I use the PrintOut command and set the Preview parameter to true it works. If I print without going to the page preview it doesn't work. If I put the code outside the WorkBook_BeforePrint method everything's ok too...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  the line 'Application.PrintCommunication = True' after you make your changes to the header